# Software to record a Khan Academy style video?

Tags: software-recommendation, video

Firstly, this question is not a duplicate of anything like https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18650/software-to-make-khan-academy-style-video-tutorials-on-ubuntu , as some may think

Secondly, I tried to record some videos using `xournal`. I want to have no menus, no UI in the video, canvas only. I also want my video to have `1280x720` dimensions (I have a `1366x768` laptop display and I'd like not to use a second hardware display).

The problem is that I can't use menus without showing them in the screen recording area. What can I do?

I thought that there should be a program which allows user to record *working area* only.

P.S. I've tried using `simplescreenrecorder` and it has a *video upscale* option. And I don't really understand what it does. Is it better to upscale it in the program (record in `854x480` and upscale to `1280x720`) or is it better to send the `854x480` to YouTube?

Comment: "Firstly, this question is not a duplicate as some may think." Not a duplicate of what?

Comment: @muru of some other question =)

Comment: Which other question?

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18650/software-to-make-khan-academy-style-video-tutorials-on-ubuntu